# tslint in visual studio shows linting errors for node_modules

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017, tslint, tsconfig

I'm using Visual studio 2017 (15.5.1) and trying to get tsLint to work correctly.  For some reason, i'm getting linting errors (in the visual studio Error List (Build+intellisense)) from all of the files in node_modules and any of my declaration (*.d.ts) files as well.  Nothing I do seems to fix the issue.  I would like to exclude those files from my errors.  Everywhere seems to think this is possible, but most examples i find aren't dealing with visual studio and i'm wondering if there is some other extra setting i'm missing.  Below are my associated files.

**tslint.json**:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint:latest",
    "tslint-config-prettier"
  ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "plugins": [ { "name": "tslint-language-service" } ],
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "scripthost",
      "es5",
      "es2015",
      "es2015.promise"
    ],
    "types": [
      "angular-ui-bootstrap",
      "angular",
      "autolinker",
      "bootbox",
      "bootstrap-notify",
      "bootstrap",
      "cldrjs",
      "dragula",
      "globalize",
      "googlemaps",
      "google.analytics",
      "imagesloaded",
      "jquery.blockui",
      "jquery.bootstrap.wizard",
      "jquery",
      "jqueryui",
      "jquery.validation",
      "jsts",
      "kendo-ui",
      "masonry-layout",
      "qtip2",
      "signalr",
      "urijs",
      "moment"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "build"
  ],
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types",
    "node_modules/moment"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true,
    "useCache": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true 
}
```